# If a form is invertible then $\forall x, \exists y$ such that $B(x,y) \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

The question is the following:

If a matrix that represents a form $B:E \times E \rightarrow K$ is invertable, show that, $\forall x_0 \in E, \exists y_0$ such that $B(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$. $E$ is an Euclidean space and K is a field.

I thought about using the fact that the invertibility of $B$ means the eigenvalues are nonzero, but couldn't really put a statement in place.

Comment: It would be nice to define what sorts of things $E,K$ are.  If $E$ is a vector space over $K$,  we should want to exclude $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix $A$ is in the basis $(e_i)$, let $B_0(e_i,e_j)=\delta_{ij}$ be the scalar product, $B(x,y)=B_0(A(x),y)$, if $A$ is invertible $A(x)\neq 0 $ if $x\neq 0$ and  there exists $y$ such that $B_0(A(x),y)\neq 0$ since $B_0$ is non degenerated, write for example $A(x)=u_1e_1+..+u_ne_n$ there exists $i$ such that $u_i\neq 0$, $B(A(x),e_i)\neq 0$.